# Angular 1 how to properly include external component inside ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Situation: I have a view where I'm including a fragment with ng-include. The fragment loads perfectly and works as expected when inside view where controller is defined.
My problem is, that when I want to include external component inside the "ng-include" fragment "myView.html", it doesn't show up. When including it inside the main view where the controller is, it shows up and works as expected.

Main view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div data-ng-include src="'views/myView.html'"></div>

    <!-- When loaded here, the component shows up --> 
    <!-- <div id="componentDiv"></div> -->
</div>
```

Fragment "myView.html":

```
<div>
    <div id="componentDiv"></div>
</div>
```

The component is loaded inside the "MyController", where "componentDiv" is the "id" of "div" where the component is placed:

```
var testObj = new TestObj({"container": "componentDiv"});
```

Trying to do this to be able to use this fragment with full functionality in several places.

Any ideas or suggestions what to look up or try?

Comment: Can we see your component definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO I think that by saying "...*to be able to use this fragment with full functionality in several places*" you just answered your question. What you need is to build a custom directive and use it in any place you like.

see directive samples e.g. [Angular documentation on directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Or perhaps a component

Comment: If you use Angukar 2 or 4 it will be component if you use AngularJS it will be directive.

Comment: there are components in AngularJS too since 1.5